# Access collection through MVVM Command

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps

In my ViewModel i Have base Card class and Deck class which contain Observable Collection of Cards. Here is how it is bound in XAML

```
        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding DeckCollection}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=??}"
                            CommandParameter=??
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image 
                                    Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                                    Stretch="None"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Here are my classes

```
class Deck
{
    private ObservableCollection<Card> _deckCollection = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    public ObservableCollection<Card> DeckCollection
    {
        get { return _deckCollection; }
        set { _deckCollection = value; }
    }

    public Deck()
    {
        ActionCommand = new MyCommand();
        ActionCommand.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true;
        ActionCommand.ExecuteFunc = AddToList;
    }


    public void AddToList(object parameter)
    {
       var clickedCard = this;
       //add Card to list which in this case is not possible
       //DeckCollection.Add(this) ?
    }
}

class Card
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public String ImagePath { get; set; }
    public MyCommand ActionCommand { get; set; }
}
```

And also MyCommand class

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{

    public Predicate<object> CanExecuteFunc { get; set; }
    public Action<object> ExecuteFunc { get; set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }
}
```

I have made suggested changes but right now ActionCommand is not visible within collection, as only properties that belong to Card class can be bound.

EDIT:I have changed my XAML file for following but got some errors

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Deck}, Path=ActionCommand}}">
```

The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'.

The property 'Path' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'.

The member "AncestorType" is not recognized or is not accessible.

The member "Path" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Unknown member 'AncestorType' on element 'RelativeSource'

Unknown member 'Path' on element 'RelativeSource'

Please help

Comment: Where is the viewmodel for your XAML? Is that where `CardCollection`  is defined? Conceptually, if you have a card class and are calling a 'add to list' method on it I'd expect you to be passing it a list, otherwise how will the card know what to add itself to? More reasonable though would be to have a method on the list itself called 'add card', which you pass a card. Both of these methods though will need to be managed through the viewmodel, which is orchestrating these actions.

Comment: I have made many changes in my code and now i see that i left CardCollection instead of changing it to DeckCollection. So basically my Deck class is my ViewModel and it is bound directly as ItemSource in GridView

Comment: Ok got it. Well make the command a command on your viewmodel (deck) and as a parameter to the command specify the card (or have a SelectedCard property on the VM). Then add to your list that way - from the deck using a card, not the other way around.

Comment: I have made some modifications but still cant bind command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have button which adds new items to your collection, I think something like that can be the solution.

In XAML:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding DeckCollection}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button>
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                                Stretch="None"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
<!-- public property located in Deck class -->
<Button Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" Content="Add Item"/>
```

In C#:

```
    class Deck, INotifyPropertyChanged /*custom implementation depends on .NET version, in my case its .NET3.5*/
    {
    private ObservableCollection<Card> _deckCollection = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    public ObservableCollection<Card> DeckCollection
    {
        get { return _deckCollection; }
        set { _deckCollection = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged(() => DeckCollection); }
    }

    // your Add command
    public ICommand AddItemCommand { get { return new MyCommand(AddToList); } }
    private void AddToList(object parameter)
    {
       DeckCollection.Add(new Card());
    }

    public Deck() { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression) 
    {
       if (PropertyChanged == null) return;

       var body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
       if (body != null) PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(body.Member.Name));
    }
}
```

The main thing in this situation is that you cannot have the add button inside the collection.